# Store browserHistory using history.js in react redux architecture with SSR

Tags: redux, react-router, browser-history, history.js, react-router-redux

How can one persist the full router history of a user visiting an SSR react-redux app? I have tried modifying the react-redux-router package's reducer.js file as such...but when the user loads via SSR, the history array is reset.

```
/**
 * This action type will be dispatched when your history
* receives a location change.
   */
export const LOCATION_CHANGE = '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE'

 const initialState = {
    locationBeforeTransitions: null,
    locationHistory: []
}

/**
 * This reducer will update the state with the most recent location history 
 * has transitioned to. This may not be in sync with the router,     particularly
 * if you have asynchronously-loaded routes, so reading from and relying on
 * this state is discouraged.
 */
 export function routerReducer(state = initialState, { type, payload } = {})         {
 if (type === LOCATION_CHANGE) {

return { ...state,
  locationBeforeTransitions: payload,
  locationHistory: state.locationHistory.concat([payload]) }
 }

return state
}
```

ref: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux/blob/master/src/reducer.js

However, I think this is *supposed to be achieved in a middleware*.

Irregardless, this (storing the entire previous session history) seems like a common enough use case that *perhaps someone has already formulated a best practice.??*

Perhaps even this full history is accessible via the historyjs object in react-router w/o react-router-redux.

I'm looking for answers to how to fulfill storing the full history of a user's session in the redux state and post it to my api server when the user closes the browser or navigates away from the site. (if this is not possible, i could just post it upon every navigation.) Then I would like to show this history in a 'recently viewed' list of pages on the users' home pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't have to meddle with the internals of `react-redux-router`.

As you can see in the code you presented, `react-redux-router` exports a `LOCATION_CHANGE` action.

You can use this action in a reducer of your own. Here's an example:

```
// locationHistoryReducer.js
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux';

export default function locationHistory(state = [], action) {
  if (action.type === LOCATION_CHANGE) {
    return state.concat([action.payload]);
  }
  return state;
}
```

However, this may be unnecessary. Your assumption that this can be be achieved with [middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) is correct. Here's an example of a middleware layer:

```
const historySaver = store => next => action => {
  if (action.type === LOCATION_CHANGE) {
    // Do whatever you wish with action.payload
    // Send it an HTTP request to the server, save it in a cookie, localStorage, etc.
  }
  return next(action)
}
```

And here's how to apply that layer in the store:

```
let store = createStore(
  combineReducers(reducers),
  applyMiddleware(
    historySaver
  )
)
```

Now, how you save and load data is entirely up to you (and has nothing to do with react-router and the browser's history).

In the official docs, they recommend [injecting the initial state on the server side](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.md#inject-initial-component-html-and-state) using a `window.__PRELOADED_STATE__` variable.